# MySQL from last specific month

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have database with toners. I need to get result only from lastest spetember every year to currrent date.

```
SELECT * FROM used_toners WHERE date >= '01-09-2018' # but after september of 2019 I need date '01-09-2019' and so on
```

Comment: What does "lastest september every year" mean?

Comment: If this year already was september, return this year september. If it is before september, return last year september.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this query I select all the ranges of dates from September of last year to September of this year.

```
SELECT *
FROM used_toners
WHERE (YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
    AND MONTH(`date`) BETWEEN 9 AND 12)
OR (YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND MONTH(`date`) BETWEEN 1 AND 9)
```

Here you can find `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want data from all Septembers, you can use `month()` or similar functions:

```
SELECT ut.*
FROM used_toners ut
WHERE MONTH(date) = 9;
```

Comment: I want data from last september till now. This return result from every september.